# custom firebase singleton class to reduce lines of code android app development

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, singleton

I was wondering if it would be beneficial to create a custom Firebase class which stores database references and storage references as an attribute so that you don't need to keep initialising:

```
DatabaseReference = Firebase.getInstance().getReference.get(UserUid)
```

In every activity that u require to use the database Reference. I was thinking along the lines of this?

```
  public FirebaseMethods(Context context) {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(getUserUid());
    mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mContext = context;

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }
}
```

Although I have yet to make it a singleton class. Then in any of the activities I would just call FirebaseMethods.getInstance().getReference() to get the database reference directly. Would this be a good practice to use?

Answer (score 2):

> Would this be a good practice to use?

It will, but only because you are reducing the number of the lines of code. In terms of connectivity, if you are instantiating a Firebase database more than once, it doesn't mean that you are creating a new connection each time. You are creating a new object but it will still be **only one open connection** to the Firebase servers.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?